# How to prove this greedy solution?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Given an array of positive integers you are allowed to increase any element by one for once, your goal is to maximize the multiplication of all the elements
For example:

Input:

$5$

$1$ $6$ $5$ $8$ $1$

Output:

$2$ $6$ $5$ $8$ $1$

Greedy solution:

increase the minimum element of the array

Can anyone proof this solution?

Comment: If the initial product was $S$, and you increased the value of $x_i$ to $x_i+1$, what is the new product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements of the array are $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$, we want to maximize $$x_1x_2\cdots x_{r-1}(1+x_r)x_{r+1}\cdots x_n$$

$$=x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_n(1+\frac{1}{x_r})$$

Since the first part is constant, we want to maximize $1+\frac{1}{x_r}$, that is, we want to minimize $x_r$.